# styles and scripts not loading in my magento website after git pull

Tags: magento

After i pull changes from development server to production server the styles and scripts are
not loading up in the html as shown below

[image]

I tried restarting the server and php service and cleared the caceh under /var/cache folder.

what i am guessing is its because of Cache, but i cannot disable cache under admin panel as all the scripts are not added to head.

how do i disable all cache in this scenario?
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue, i did the below things

1) Removed `var/cache`

2) Restarted my web server and php service

3) Disabled my compiler path through shell

and it worked just like that.

Answer (score 1):

If you have SSH access, go to `var/cache/` and rm -rf. I wrote a php script to do exactly that, too, so my staff doesn't have to use SSH when an extension's developer tells us to "manually delete all the cache".

Answer (score 1):

I think you can refresh the Cache in the Admin; dont have to disable, if you are not allowed. 
Also, please clear the browser cache.

Three main caches, besides from any other 3rd party cache package you might have installed, its best practise to clear

1. var/cache
2. Magento Admin =>System->Cache Management(Refresh the cache based on your requirement).
3. Browser cache

Cheers,
Swapna

Comment: Please note i have mentioned that the admin panel is completely in accessible because of scripts not loading properly..